# What is the algorithm to deduplicate 1 trillion data items?

Tags: duplicates

Suppose there are a trillion key value pairs that are far too large than memory can hold, what is the algorithm to filter out duplicate? The data can be from a stream or a file, which is also a stream.

I tried using hashtable for the filtering process, but eventually memory runs out (with a smaller dataset, but problem is same). This initially seems a light problem, but actually not a small problem. It would require a whole database for detecting duplicate keys, right?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. I would recommend reading through [SO tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and through SO help center on [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then you can try editing your question to include more information so we can narrow down your problem and help you. As is this question is to broad. Also, do pay attention to part "Include all relevant tags" in how to ask article. You currently have only one tag with just 122 watchers so this question will probably not reach relevant people who can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the list, then remove duplicates.  A card sort will work on any size data set.

Comment: That is interesting idea. But sorting will take a long time and if stream keeps coming, it may not be able to sort again.

Comment: If the data set is continuously expanding, sorting it is the only sane way be able to deduplicate the incoming data.